# Помогите сделать для этой функции возможность ввода данных от SMTP

Tags: php, smtp

Всем привет, мне нужна помощь. Ломаю голову, не понимаю, как можно создать для моего кода возможность ввода данных от SMTP, чтобы пользователю приходило письмо с подтверждением

```
        $name = $res['Name'];
        $pname = md5($name);
        $ppass = md5($res['Pass']);
        $time = md5(date('d'));
        $keyone = $pname.$ppass.$time;
        $key = sha1($keyone);
        $date = date('d.m.Y');

        $ridacc = $res['ID'];
        $remail = $res['Email'];

        mysql_query("INSERT INTO `ZZrecovery` (`key`, `idacc`, `email`, `typerec`, `name`, `ipp`, `date`, `date2`) VALUES ('$key', '$ridacc', '$remail', '$typerec', '$name', '$ip', '$date', NOW())");

        $to      = ''.$res['Email'].'';
        $subject = 'Восстановление доступа';
        $message = '
        <html>
            <head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
            <title>Восстановление доступа</title>
         </head>
         <body>
                txt, <font style="font-size: 10pt;"><b>'.$name.'</b></font><br><br>

                text  <br>
                http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/index.php?rec='.$key.'&server='.$server.' <br><br>

                text  <br>
                С уважением, Администрация <font style="font-size: 10pt;"><b>Proekt.Ru</b></font>
         </body>
        </html>';
        $headers = 'To: <'.$res['Email'].'>' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'From: Proek.Ru <mail@domen.ru>' . "\r\n";
        $headers .=  'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=cp1251' . "\r\n";

        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        if($typerec == 1) return 0;
        else if($typerec == 2) return 3;
    }
}
```

Comment: Покажите что пробовали сделать самостоятельно и с чем возникла ошибка. Тогда обязательно поможем. Информации же куча в интернете. Не поверю, что не смогли найти.

Comment: Пробовал множество методов в интернете которые были, так и не получилось, письмо не доходило до моей почты, показывать не вижу смысла, т.к всё удалил, поэтому обратился сюда за помощью

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Вот рабочий пример отправки писем через смтп амазона

```
function get_data($smtp_conn) {
$data="";
while($str = fgets($smtp_conn,515)) {
$data .= $str;
if(substr($str,3,1) == " ") {break;}
}
//echo $data.'<br />'; // Раскоментировать для отладки
}


$smtp_conn = fsockopen("tls://...amazonaws.com", 465, $errno, $errstr, 10);
$data = get_data($smtp_conn);
fputs($smtp_conn,"EHLO ...amazonaws.com\r\n");
$data = get_data($smtp_conn);
fputs($smtp_conn,"AUTH LOGIN\r\n");
$data = get_data($smtp_conn);
fputs($smtp_conn,base64_encode($conf_user)."\r\n");
$data = get_data($smtp_conn);
fputs($smtp_conn,base64_encode($conf_password)."\r\n");
$data = get_data($smtp_conn);
fputs($smtp_conn,"MAIL FROM:from@adr.com\r\n");
$data = get_data($smtp_conn);
fputs($smtp_conn,"RCPT TO:".$email."\r\n");
$data = get_data($smtp_conn);
fputs($smtp_conn,"DATA\r\n");
$data = get_data($smtp_conn);
// Признаком конца почтового сообщения является точка в самом начале строки, за которой следует.
fputs($smtp_conn,$mailheaders.$message."\r\n.\r\n");
$data = get_data($smtp_conn);
fputs($smtp_conn,"QUIT\r\n");
$data = get_data($smtp_conn);
fclose($smtp_conn);
```

Comment: Извини, а можно как-то под мой код это реализовать? Я не понимаю, как  именно в этом коде с Амазона сделать под своё

Comment: Надо у себя вместо mail() добавить этот код. В fsockopen поставить свой хост и порт. И левым переменным присвоить свои значения

Comment: Блин, а можно тебя попросить, взять сверху мой код и добавить его туда, ибо у меня почему-то не получается, я не понимаю, что на что менять. Буду очень благодарен и признателен тебе, если поможешь

Comment: Добавил этот код, не знаю, правильно или неправильно я туда ввёл данные, в итоге, мне письмо не приходит.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/eJRKjeo

Comment: Раскоментируй echo $data и открой скрипт в браузере

Comment: Раскоментировал, а вот как открыть скрипт в браузере?

Comment: "Hello World!" работает?

Comment: В смысле? Не понимаю.

Comment: Причём здесь "Hello World!", если такого в коде нет, я вообще не понимаю